# How to swap content of void pointers?

Tags: c++

I'm making a function which receives array of any datatype and reverse it elements.

```
void f(void *p, int size)
{
  for(int i=0; i<=size/2; i++)
  {
    swap(p+i, p+size-i-1);
  }
}
```

but problem is how can i implement swap function which swap their content without dereferencing void pointers?

Comment: You can't. That's why C++ has templates. They solve this problem.

Comment: We should know not only the whole size of the array, but also the size of one block of the array. So the function should be `void* f(void*p, size_t blockSize, size_t wholeSize)`. Then according to the blockSize, choose a suitable-size integer pointer and point it to `p`, and do the swap.

Comment: BTW, clear up if it's C or C++. Because generic programming are very different from one language to another.

Comment: Reformatting the code for some logical errors.

Comment: This shouldn't even compile: You cannot perform arithmetic on void pointers, so you cannot say `p + i`.

Comment: @Kerrek yes! We can, but we can't dereference it.

Comment: @furquan: But it's not well-defined. For `T* p`, `p + 1` advances the value of `p` by `sizeof(T)`, but there is no `sizeof(void)`!

Comment: @Kerrek i didnt study templates yet.

Comment: I didn't use any templates. I was just making a general point about any type `T`.

Comment: @Kerrek Yea it boggles my mind too but GCC allows it.

Comment: Use your compiler in conforming mode -- you can try for instance `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++03`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or you could use the std::reverse function

```
int main()
{
    int  data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    std::reverse(data, data + sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]));

}
```

Comment: +1 vote for the brief answer in C++. (I don't know why there's a -1 vote... it's surely a good solution).

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged as C++, I'm assuming that you can use template. One possible solution:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T *p, int size) {
    for(int i=0;i<=size/2;i++) {
        swap(p[i], p[size-i-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use swap(). That way if the type has its own effecient version of swap() this will be used. ie if T == std::vector<int> you get a much more effecient swap than using a temporary (as you are copying the vector multiple times).

Comment: Also the identifier _T is reserved in most situations so best to avoid it.

Comment: i think we cannot use '[]' with void pointers.Correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @furqan: In the same way you can't do pointer arithmatic on void*. That is why the function is templated so that it gets the real type information and not void*

Comment: @furqan After reading Martin's comments I googled it and findout that some libraries define a macro named _T, not a reserved keyword but still good to avoid.

Comment: @fbafelipe: The compiler and libraries that go with the compiler are allowed to use _T as an identifier. `You` as a developer are **NOT**. see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Comment: @furqan: If you think it allows it then you are doing something else (not what I think you are doing). Pointer asthmatic on a void pointer is meaningless and thus you get a compile time error: `pointer of type ‘void *’ used in arithmetic`

Answer (score 2):

An ugly C example, enjoy it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void* f(void * p, size_t blockSize, size_t wholeSize){
    int i;
    unsigned char *begin, *end, temp;

    begin = (unsigned char*) p;
    end = (unsigned char*) p + wholeSize - blockSize;

    while(end>begin){
        for(i=0; i<blockSize; i++){
            temp = begin[i];
            begin[i] = end[i];
            end[i] = temp;
        }
        begin += blockSize;
        end -= blockSize;
    }

    return p;
}

int main()
{
    int i;

    double da[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int ia[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    char ca[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    f(da, sizeof(da[0]), sizeof(da));
    f(ia, sizeof(ia[0]), sizeof(ia));
    f(ca, sizeof(ca[0]), sizeof(ca));

    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("da[%d]=%lf ia[%d]=%d ca[%d]=%d\n", i, da[i], i, ia[i], i, (int)ca[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @furqan: I'd like to comment the efficiency of the function may be low, because of the one-byte operation... however, maybe it's fit for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you use C++ then why not to use `template`s:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T* const p,int size)  // return changed to `void`
{
  // same logic
}
```

This will create a copy of this function `f` for any type you pass (e.g. `int[]`, `char[]`, `A[]`). Above function can still be improved if you want:

```
template<typename T, int size>
void f(T (&p)[size])  // don't have to pass sizeof array explicitly
{
  // same logic
}
```

usage:

```
int a[] = { ... };
f(a);
```

Comment: Actually I'm first year student, Didn't know about templates and memcpy and size_t.I'm doing my hobby project for self learning which i dont know how it is tagged homework.Is there any other way?

Comment: @furqan, other ways are there but not cleaner. Also, I am not using `size_t` or `memcpy` here; just your same logic with `template`s

Comment: Note: `p+size-i` should be `p+size-i-1`. You have an off by one error.

Comment: Note that you want to swap p[i] with p[size-i-1], not p[size-i]. That would cause a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.
You need at least the size of one element of the array.

Or if it's not C but C++ you can make the function a template.

Answer (score -1):

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t size) {
  char buf[size]; //can be malloc if size to too big

  memcpy(temp, b,    size);
  memcpy(b,    a,    size);
  memcpy(a,    temp, size);
}
```

Comment: You missunderstood what he wants. He wants to swap the content of one array (reverse it), not exchange two array.

Comment: Using memcpy is a bad idea in C++ and nearly always wrong. This is because most types have copy/move constructors that have side effects.