# How to correctly swap void pointers?

Tags: c++

I have a task:
I need to swap an elements in array, by **"void pointers based"** swap function. Its a simple bubble sort algorithm.
But my `void SwapInt(void *x, void *y)` function doesnt work! I mean it called correctly, but did nothing. My pre-sorting array doesnt change. What could be wrong here and how it fix?

```
void SwapInt(void *x, void *y)
{
    void *buffer = x;
    x = y;
    y = buffer;
}

bool CmpInt(void *x, void *y)
{
    int *intPtrX = static_cast<int*>(x);
    int *intPtrY = static_cast<int*>(y);
    if(*intPtrX > *intPtrY)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Sort(int array[], int nTotal, size_t size, void (*ptrSwapInt)(void *x, void *y), bool (*ptrCmpInt)(void *x, void *y))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nTotal; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < nTotal - 1; j++)
        {
          if (ptrCmpInt(&array[j] , &array[j + 1]))
          {
            ptrSwapInt(&array[j], &array[j + 1]);
          }
        }
    }
}
```

P.S I have already visit [StackOverflow_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799006/how-to-swap-content-of-void-pointers) and [StackOverflow_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667385/swap-on-void-array-doesnt-work-correctly), and I still dont have a clue, what is wrong.

Comment: You know there's a standard `std::swap` function that works very well, right? Why is your `SwapInt` taking two `void*` btw? Two `int&` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: You need a pointer or reference to those pointers if you want to affect them outside the function.

Comment: You change local variables, to change what is passed, use `void SwapInt(void **x, void **y)` or `void SwapInt(void *&x, void *&y)`

Comment: Do you want to swap the pointers themselves or do you want to swap the things they point to? If `x` points to `1` and `y` points to `2`, do you want to swap the `1` and the `2` so `x` still points to the same place but that place now contains a `2`? Or do you want to swap `x` and `y` so `x` now points to a different place but that place still contains the same `2` it contained before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't swap integers by swapping pointers, you have to **dereference** the pointers. And to do that you have to cast them to the int pointers that they really are.

```
void SwapInt(void *x, void *y)
{
    int temp = *static_cast<int*>(x);
    *static_cast<int*>(x) = *static_cast<int*>(y);
    *static_cast<int*>(y) = temp;
}
```

In fact you did this perfectly correctly in your `CmpInt` function, so I'm not sure what the problem in `SwapInt` was.

Comment: Its helped! I thought about it, but in my opinion it was like "bad style" . Now I see, that I wasn`t right. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well the whole exercise is bad style. It's the kind of coding you would do in C not C++ (but I realise that this isn't your choice).